# SSIS -Sharepoint List Source Dynamic connection

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I am creating a SSIS Packages through Share point Source but i am not able to create dynamic source connection in SSIS Packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below screenshot, replace the property which you want to set dynamically with variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanq I got the Solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS Packages using Kingswasoft extension:
look at link below:
https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-sharepoint